# Using criteria in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Ok I searched through many different places unfortunately it might be easier to ask,

I have to select some data then set salary to increase by 10 percent where my criteria is on another table this is my code

```
 Select E.Lastname, E.Salary, J.EEO1Classification from Employee as E
 Join JobTitle as J
 on E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID 
 Update Employee
 set Salary = (Salary * .10) + Salary
 where [JobTitle.EEO1Classification] = 'Office/Clerical'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? SQL Server?

Comment: You need two different queries? Or a block(procedure) containing two queries? Both sow and update? Because if want to select just to update then Fred's answer gives you all that you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you may be trying to achive. Basically an `UPDATE` using a `JOIN` to the `JobTitle` table

**MySQL**

```
UPDATE Employee E
INNER JOIN JobTitle as J
  ON E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID 
SET Salary = (Salary * .10) + Salary
WHERE [J.EEO1Classification] = 'Office/Clerical'
```

**Alternate syntax**

```
UPDATE
    e
SET
    Salary = (Salary * .10) + Salary
FROM
    Employee E
    JOIN
    JobTitle J ON E.JobTitleID = J.JobTitleID 
WHERE
    J.EEO1Classification = 'Office/Clerical'
```

Comment: What error do u get? syntactical? Can you confirm what db u are using?

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'J.EEO1Classification'.

Comment: Alternative text gives me this  Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: Alternative one worked I had to add cast(J.EEO1) you go it thanks . :)

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Employee e
SET e.Salary = e.Salary * 1.1
WHERE e.JobTitleID IN 
( SELECT j.JobTitleID FROM JobTitle j 
        WHERE j.EEO1Classification = 'Office/Clerical'
)
```

Comment: I am Using T-SQL and for some reason this script is not working.

Comment: The concept works, but without seeing the error message you're getting or the DDL for your tables, I don't know how much data type casting is required for this particular update.